# Sort table in view without database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I want to do a ranking. I have in my database many users and I want to do a ranking with them, but I don't know how to.

I need to get data from many tables in my database for some calculations. I already do this in a view. It will show the data and calculations, but I have a problem. Is it possible to sort the table columns?

This way, I'm sorting in the view rather than the database.

I'm searching, but I've only found references to sort tables within the database.

Sorry for my english, I'm learning.

Thanks

Comment: Use jquery table sorter for sorting the columns on view...here are the links please check https://datatables.net/ and http://tablesorter.com/docs/

Comment: Thanks a lot, I found a example in github with a example using datatable, https://github.com/adrianotadao/datatables-example/, thanks a lot, I will to use that =]